# Function of a monotone map

Tags: functions

Suppose that I have a function $f(x)$ such that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ monotone in $x$. Then consider a function $g(x)=\alpha f(x)$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Can I say that also $g(x)$ is monotone in $x$ and that it is monotone increasing if $f(x)$ is montone increasing (decreasing) and $\alpha>0$ ($\alpha<0$)?

Comment: Yes you can say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes $f$ being monotone increasing means that $f'(x)\ge 0,\forall x\in\Bbb R$

Then $g'(x)=\alpha f'(x)\ge 0$ if $\alpha\ge 0$, and $\le 0$ if $\alpha\lt 0$.

So the property follows :)

Comment: How do you know $f$ is differentiable?